say a quarter over
The following excerpt is from Charles Dickens's David Copperfield.

In search of the principle on which joints ought to be roasted, to be
roasted enough, and not too much, I myself referred to the Cookery
Book, and found it there established as the allowance of a quarter of
an hour to every pound, and say a quarter over. But the principle
always failed us by some curious fatality, and we never could hit any
medium between redness and cinders.

I'm not sure what is meant by a quarter over in the cooking instructions. Is it trying to say the allowance is 15 minutes (to be none-too-rare, but still not burnt), but for these 'joints' he should go somewhat over 15 minutes? If so that's very vague, no wonder they have charcoal for dinner. Though so is the wording of the text here...
